# Error Retrieving Firebase data:

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to implement the code [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html) from Firebase Retrieving Data example.

The code is as follows and below is the error too:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
}
});
```

This is the error I get:

> Class 'Anonymous class derived from ValueEventListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onCancelled(DatabaseError' in ValueEventListener

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: It appears that somehow you are mixing the old Firebase SDK 2.x with the new, 3.x.  Can you post the dependencies from your build.gradle?  `FirebaseError` is from the old SDK, `DatabaseError`, the new.

Comment: You are right I am on the new Firebase SDK: `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'`, I am researching the new SDK now ...